# Convert the JSON to CSV using java

Tags: java, json, csv

I'm trying to convert the JSON to CSV file. But I'm facing the issue in the
JSONArray docs = output.getJSONArray("Text will vary from each execution.");
How to take the value of the getJSONArray(" xxx ")  ???

```
 JSONObject output = new JSONObject(jsonString);
 JSONArray docs = output.getJSONArray("elements");
 File file=new File(csvFilepath);
 String csv = CDL.toString(docs);
 FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, csv);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question.

Comment: what your not understanding in my question

Comment: No, I am not understanding your question.

Answer (score 0):

I got the output with the below code

```
String[] Names=output.getNames(output);
JSONArray docs =output.getJSONArray(Names[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert JSON document to CSV then you can try the library [json2flat](https://github.com/opendevl/Json2Flat).

It takes any dynamic JSON document and tries to convert it into a suitable format.

For code usage and sample JSON conversion please [click on this link.](https://github.com/opendevl/Json2Flat)

Answer (score -1):

That would depend on the structure of your JSON, and the expected layout of the CSV.

There's no cut and paste answer to that, you're going to have to put in some actual effort to map things the way you need them to be mapped.

Select the objects you need from the JSON, then walk through the resulting array and map each to a row in your CSV.

Nothing too strenuous, just plain old loop iteration and file handling.

Answer (score -2):

Something like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        String numbers = "{\"test\":[{\"elements\" : \"1\"},{\"elements\":\"2\"},{\"elements\":\"3\"}]}";
        JSONObject output = new JSONObject(numbers);
        JSONArray docs = output.getJSONArray("test");

        for (int i = 0; i < docs.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(docs.get(i));
        }

    }
```